# How do I cleanly remove fzf integration from fish?

Tags: fish, fzf

I installed fzf (https://github.com/junegunn/fzf#fish-shell) using brew on Mac. The other day I removed it using brew.

Now I get the following message whenever I open a fish shell:

```
fish: 
  fzf_key_bindings
  ^
in function '__original_fish_user_key_bindings'
        called on line 46 of file ~/.local/share/omf/init.fish
in function 'fish_user_key_bindings'
in function '__fish_reload_key_bindings'
        called on line 228 of file /usr/local/Cellar/fish/3.1.2/share/fish/functions/__fish_config_interactive.fish
in function '__fish_config_interactive'
        called on line 170 of file /usr/local/Cellar/fish/3.1.2/share/fish/config.fish
in function '__fish_on_interactive'
in event handler: handler for generic event 'fish_prompt'
```

How do I cleanly remove the fzf integration from here?

Answer (score 1):

fzf installs itself in fish shell by appending to `fish_user_key_bindings`.

You can remove its integration by editing `~/.config/fish/functions/fish_user_key_bindings.fish` and deleting the call to `fzf_key_bindings`.

If you have installed fzf by running its `install` script, you can also run its `uninstall` script of course.